# How use guave cache loader in F polymorphic code

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s, cats-effect

I have a service, that returns joke   [from official example](https://github.com/ChristopherDavenport/http4s-client-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/chrisdavenport/clientexample/Jokes.scala):

```
  final case class JokeError(e: Throwable) extends RuntimeException

  def impl[F[_] : Sync](C: Client[F]): Jokes[F] = new Jokes[F] {
    val dsl = new Http4sClientDsl[F] {}
    import dsl._
    def get: F[Jokes.Joke] = {
      C.expect[Joke](GET(uri"https://icanhazdadjoke.com/"))
        .adaptError { case t => JokeError(t) }
    }
  }
```

But I want cache first requested joke (just by constant key, this doesn't matter) with guava cache:

```
object Jokes {
  def apply[F[_]](implicit ev: Jokes[F]): Jokes[F] = ev

  final case class Joke(joke: String) extends AnyRef
  object Joke {
    implicit val jokeDecoder: Decoder[Joke] = deriveDecoder[Joke]
    implicit def jokeEntityDecoder[F[_]: Sync]: EntityDecoder[F, Joke] =
      jsonOf
    implicit val jokeEncoder: Encoder[Joke] = deriveEncoder[Joke]
    implicit def jokeEntityEncoder[F[_]: Applicative]: EntityEncoder[F, Joke] =
      jsonEncoderOf
  }

  final case class JokeError(e: Throwable) extends RuntimeException

  def impl[F[_]: Sync](C: Client[F]): Jokes[F] = new Jokes[F]{

    val cacheLoader : CacheLoader[String, Joke] = new CacheLoader[String, Joke] {
      override def load(key: String): Joke = {
        import dsl._
        val joke: F[Joke] = C.expect[Joke](GET(uri"https://icanhazdadjoke.com/"))
          .adaptError{ case t => JokeError(t)}
        //? F[Joke] => Joke
        null
      }
    }

    val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(cacheLoader)

    val dsl = new Http4sClientDsl[F]{}

    def get: F[Jokes.Joke] = {
       //it's ok?
       cache.get("constant").pure[F]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `cacheLoader` requires "materialized" value `F[Joke] => Joke`. And cache return pure value without `F`

How can I use this cache in `F` polymorpic code?

Comment: For me line `val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(cacheLoader)` produces `Error:(52, 43) inferred type arguments [String,io.chrisdavenport.clientexample.Jokes.Joke] do not conform to method build's type parameter bounds [K1 <: Object,V1 <: Object]
    val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(cacheLoader)`. guava 28.1-jre.

Comment: Edited `extends AnyVal` => `extends AnyRef`. Now compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking how to run code polymorphic in `F`, to do so you need an `Effect` constraint to your `F`.

Also instead of using `pure`, you would need to use `delay`, since getting a value from the cache is a side effect.

```
val cacheLoader : CacheLoader[String, Joke] = new CacheLoader[String, Joke] {
  override def load(key: String): Joke = {
    import dsl._
    val joke: F[Joke] = C.expect[Joke](GET(uri"https://icanhazdadjoke.com/"))
      .adaptError{ case t => JokeError(t)}

    // This is a side effect, but can't avoid it due to the way the API is designed
    joke.toIO.unsafeRunSync()
  }
}

val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(cacheLoader)

val dsl = new Http4sClientDsl[F]{}

def get: F[Jokes.Joke] = {
   // This is okay :)
   Sync[F].delay(cache.get("constant"))
}
```

As an aside, if you want to use something that interoperates really well with http4s, I strongly recommend `mules`. Check it out here: 
https://github.com/ChristopherDavenport/mules